# How to Find a Professor for a Summer Internship in My Field?

Tags: research-process, academic-life, internship, networking

I'm an undergraduate student looking to gain practical experience in my field of study through a summer internship. I understand that working under the guidance of a professor can be incredibly beneficial. However, I'm unsure about the best approach to finding a professor willing to take on an intern for the summer.

Could someone advise me on identifying and reaching out to professors for such opportunities?

I also saw a kinda same question, but it was mostly about summer internship programs and not professors. That's why I've asked this question.

Comment: Look around your institution and talk to people.

Comment: where are you? for people in the US, see https://www.nsf.gov/crssprgm/reu/ I bet Europe has similar programs. not sure about other countries.

Comment: In my field you don't want a summer internship with a professor, you want to do a longer term research project; ideally more than a year but a year is fine. You may be able to work more summer hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start looking at relevant papers, and see the authors.
Perhaps early-career professors will benefit the most from being supervisors (looks good on the CV). It is important that you stress that you (your school/government) provides the funding needed.
Make sure you do as much administrative work as possible (finding a place to live, etc.) and not rely on the supervisor for this.